# php imap_mail do not develiver email

Tags: php, imap

Hi guys I am trying to send email via imap_mail function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail.php

```
$to = implode(", ", $sentTo);
$subject = $email_info['subject'];
$body = wordwrap($email_info['body']);
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0;\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit;\r\n"
                        . "From: " . $account_doc->email . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $account_doc->email . "\r\n";
$return_path = $account_doc->email;
$cc = implode(", ", $sentCC);
$bcc = implode(", ", $sentBCC);

if ( strlen($cc) === 0 ) $cc = NULL;
if ( strlen($bcc) === 0 ) $bcc = NULL;
if ( strlen($subject) === 0 ) $subject = "-";

$is_sent = imap_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, $cc, $bcc, $return_path);

if ($is_sent) {
    imap_append( $connection , $account_doc->activeFolders->SENT
                    , "MIME-Version: 1.0;\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit;\r\n"
                            . "From: {$this->userDoc->name}\r\nTo: {$to}\r\nSubject: {$subject}\r\nDate: " . date("r", strtotime("now")) . "\r\n\r\n{$body}\r\n"
                    );

imap_close($connection);

$this->json_response("Email is sent");
```

imap_mail function return true, and email is appended and I can see it in mail box.
But when I check email on which I sent those email email is not delivered.

Does anybody know what cause the problem of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IMAP`, in general, does not deliver email.  All `APPEND` does is add a message to a mail folder, it does not cause delivery.  Generally, you need to use `SMTP` for this.  A typical email client will send via `SMTP`, and then append the same message to the `SENT` folder.

Some servers, such as [Courier](http://courier-mta.org/), have an optional extension which can send email via a special Outbox folder, however this type of extension is not widely deployed or supported.